# Unable to populate the JSON data into drop down field using Angular 8 material

Tags: json, angular, angular-material

I have some existing JSON data and I need to populate those into some drop down fields using Angular 8. I am providing my code below.

```
<button mat-button (click)="openDialog('Add',{})" mat-flat-button color="primary">Add Row</button>
<div class="clear"></div>
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="my-table mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
            <mat-select placeholder="Select Option" aria-label="Select Option" (selectionChange)="onOptionTypeSelectionChanged($event,i)" formControlName="option" class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="element.Name">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let s of option" [value]="s">
                    <span *ngIf="!s">
                                                </span>
                    <span *ngIf="s">
                                                    {{s}}
                                                </span>
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Value column -->

    <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Values </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;">
            <mat-select placeholder="Select Value" aria-label="Select Value" (selectionChange)="onOptionValueSelectionChanged($event)" formControlName="value" class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="element.Value" multiple>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let s of allValuesArr[i]" [value]="s">
                    <span *ngIf="!s">
                                                </span>
                    <span *ngIf="s">
                                                    {{s}}
                                                </span>
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Action section -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" class="action-link">
            <a (click)="openDialog('Delete',i)" class="btn btn-md btn-danger text-upper" style="cursor: pointer;" *ngIf="i !== 0">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</mat-table>

</div>
```

Here Inside the table I have multiple dropdown fields when user will also click on add button new row is creating. I am providing my other TypeScript code below.

```
option: any =[
    "Size",
    "Colour"
  ]

  size: any = [
    "28",
    "30",
    "32",
    "34",
    "36",
    "38",
    "40",
    "42",
    "44"
  ]

  color: any =[
    "Black",
    "Grey",
    "White",
    "Blue",
    "Red",
    "Pink",
    "Navy blue"
  ]

  allValuesArr: any =[
    []
  ];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['Name', 'value', 'action'];

  dataSource: any[] = [
    {Name: [''], Value: ''}
  ]
  onOptionTypeSelectionChanged(event: any,index){
    console.log('value', index);
    if (event.value=='Size') {
      this.allValuesArr[index] = this.size;
    }else{
      this.allValuesArr[index] = this.color;
    }
    console.log('valueArr', this.allValuesArr[index]);
  }
openDialog(action,index) {

    if(action == 'Add'){
      this.dataSource = this.dataSource.concat([{Name: [''], Value: ''}]);
      this.allValuesArr[index]=[];
      //console.log('datas',this.allValuesArr[index]);
      //this.table.renderRows();
    }else if(action == 'Delete'){
      //this.dataSource.splice(index, 1);
      this.dataSource = this.dataSource.filter((value,key)=>{
        return key != index;
      });
    }
  }
```

Here I need to populate the below existing json data into that dropdown list.

```
"Options":[{"Value":["27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45"],"Name":"Size"},{"Value":["Navy Blue"],Name":"Colour"}]
```

I am using the below code to populate the data which is not working as expected.

```
for (let i = 0; i< Options.length; i++){
          if(i == 0 ){
            if(Options[i]['Name'] == 'Size'){
              this.allValuesArr[i] = this.size;
            }else if(Options[i]['Name'] == 'Colour'){
              this.allValuesArr[i] = this.color
            }
          }else{
            if(Options[i]['Name'] == 'Size'){
              this.openDialog('Add',i);
              this.allValuesArr[i] = this.size;
            }else if(Options[i]['Name'] == 'Colour'){
              this.openDialog('Add',i);
              this.allValuesArr[i] = this.color
            }
          }
          console.log('all arr',i, this.dataSource);
        }
```

By using my above code its not working as expected and this is like edit form. I need to populate those data into the dropdown list for the respective rows.

Answer (score 0):

a very small thing you are missing Just add property name with your instance. this might help you.

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let s of option" [value]="s">
    <span *ngIf="!s"></span>
    <span *ngIf="s">{{s.value}}</span>
</mat-option>
```

Comment: I am getting values but both field I am getting the colour value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get working demo here in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kz2zcf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

here, Your first `<mat-select>` is...

```
<mat-select placeholder="Select Option" aria-label="Select Option" 
            (selectionChange)="onOptionTypeSelectionChanged($event,i)"  
            class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="element.Name">

            <mat-option *ngFor="let s of options" [value]="s.Value">
                <span *ngIf="!s">  </span>
                <span *ngIf="s">  {{s.Name}}  </span>
            </mat-option>

</mat-select>
```

your `onOptionTypeSelectionChanged()` is...

```
onOptionTypeSelectionChanged(event: any,index){
    console.log('value', event.value + ' index is '+ index);
    this.allValuesArr[index] = event.value;
    console.log('valueArr', this.allValuesArr[index]);
}
```